# Google Calendar API setup

Tags: authentication, google-calendar-api

I'm currently developing a webapp with the Google Calendar API but while setting things up I get stuck on the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'OAuth2' does not exist in the namespace
>   'Google.Apis.Authentication' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

you can find my code on: http://pastie.org/private/yxy8mu0hc5lnfkvxbjf6g

I have added dll files which are required and the google client library..

Anybody who can help me out please?

Comment: meanwhile it seems i managed to fix this error but now get stuck on this one: 
'Google.Apis.Drive.v2.DriveService' does not contain a definition for 'Scope'

Comment: How exactly did you manage to fix this?
I am having the exact same error.

Comment: I reinstalled the nuget package OAuth2: 
PM> Install-Package OAuth2